# Generate Permutation lists in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, algorithm

How should I go about generating lists of combinations of n parents and m children in VBA without having n number of nested loops? I will end up with a total of m^n combinations.

Here's an example. Let's say I have n=3 parents (1 to 3) and m=2 children (1 to 2). I would like to generate the following arrays:

```
1 1   1 2   1 1   1 2   1 1   and so forth...(total of 8)
2 1   2 1   2 2   2 2   2 1
3 1   3 1   3 1   3 1   3 2
```

These arrays would in turn be used to index another array of data, so I would end up selecting a child of every parent branch and have all the combinations of those. I figured out how I can do this if the number of parents is constant with nested loops, however that is a problem as number of parents, n, is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun Puzzle.

```
Sub KJK()
Dim parent As Long, child As Long
parent = 3
child = 2
Dim oarr As Variant
ReDim oarr(1 To parent, 1 To child ^ parent)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To parent
    For j = 1 To child ^ parent
        oarr(i, j) = i & " " & Int(((j - 1) Mod (child ^ i)) / (child ^ i) * child) + 1
    Next j
Next i
'Output the array
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(parent, child ^ parent).Value = oarr
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

---

One note:  Child^Parent cannot exceed the column count of 16384 if pasting to the sheet.